# Why doesn't bounty end when I accept my answer and why a grace period starts?

Tags: support, bounties, accepted-answer

I had a bounty on one of my questions. It got zero answers. I found an answer and posted it and accepted it. Why didn't the bounty end at that moment?

Now it has expired. Why now there's a grace period starting? Do I need to take further steps?

If this is to solicit new or more answers, why? I already accepted an answer.

Relevant question:
[How to place breakpoints in system.web.mvc before starting an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32941655/how-to-place-breakpoints-in-system-web-mvc-before-starting-an-app)

Comment: Probably partial duplicate. If I found my own answer with no answers posted, I can just delete the question and no bounty is awarded? It seems the system is trying hard to award the bounty as late as possible even though the question poster is already happy. No answer also about the extra grace period.

Comment: This is just how the bounty system works, it's all explained in the [bounty faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work). You are free to start feature request asking to change any of those behaviors